# VBA RUEDA DINÁMICA TABLA

Tags: vba, tablas, macros, ordenar, celdas

He empezado a manejar el tema macros y VBA hace poco y tengo una duda:
La idea es generar una macro a través de la cual la primera celda de la tabla pase a la última, la segunda a la primera, la tercera a la segunda... y así sucesivamente; y que esta macro se activa cada vez que le de a los diferentes botones asignados (3 en total). He estado buscando y he encontrado ejemplo que podría adaptar pero no tengo ni idea de por donde empezar.
¿Alguna idea? me salvaríais la vida

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = 10
Range("A1").Copy Destination:=Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
For i = 1 To lastRow - 1
    Range("A" & i + 1).Copy Destination:=Range("A" & i)
Next i
```

Este código copiará el contenido de la celda A1 en la última fila (en este caso, la fila 1001), luego copiará el contenido de la celda A2 en la celda A1, y así sucesivamente hasta que se copie el contenido de la celda A999 en la celda A998. Esto moverá todas las filas hacia arriba. Adapta el valor 1000 para tu ultima fila de la tabla.
Luego incluyes un boton en Programador-Insertar-Boton [le das nombre] y a Nuevo. Y pegas el codigo

Comment: bueno, en el codigo he puesto 10 en vez de 1000, estaba probando. cambia el valor de lastRow por la ultima fila de tu tabla.